# Obtener el valor correcto del TreeMap según su clave

Tags: java

Dado el siguiente treemap con objetos "Cliente", cuando trato de obtener el valor Cliente mediante la clave, que es un teléfono, siempre obtengo como resultado al último cliente, ¿Alguien ve donde tengo el fallo?

```
    // Creamos clientes     
     Cliente c1 = new Cliente("PePe","pereZ Sanz","02/09/2021","615251426","calle mar,8");       
     Cliente c2 = new Cliente("BARtolo","gIl miNguez","12/01/12","653654874","avenida principal,21");
     Cliente c3 = new Cliente("pILar","marTinEz oChoa","14/03/87","763654855","calle Victoria,32");
     Cliente c4 = new Cliente("mAriSA","MaZon hErnandez","22/12/10","863654874","calle soria,1");
     Cliente c5 = new Cliente("mAnuEL","SanCHEZ orTiZ","13/11/45","987654321","calle valencia,45");
    
     
    //TreeMap para indexar telefono/cliente
    TreeMap<String,Cliente> tm = new TreeMap<String,Cliente>();
    tm.put("615251426",c1); 
    tm.put("653654874",c2); 
    tm.put("763654855",c3);
    tm.put("863654874",c4);
    tm.put("987654321",c5);

    String phone;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nINTRODUZCA TELÉFONO (0 SALIR): ");
    phone = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Cliente encontrado: "+tm.get(phone));
```

Comment: por favor anade ejemplos de input y output

Comment: OK, si por ejemplo pongo cualquier teléfono contenido en un Cliente, siempre va coger el nombre del útlmo cliente.                             INTRODUZCA TELÉFONO (0 SALIR): 615251426

Cliente encontrado: manuel SANCHEZ ORTIZ

Comment: no puedo reproducir la problema. Puede postear el class `Cliente` aqui? Y cual version de java usas?

Comment: He probado con   System.out.println(tm.keySet());
     System.out.println(tm.values());   Las claves que me duevuelve con el keySet son correctas, pero en el caso de values, me duevuelve cinco veces el mismo valor, que es el ultimo nombre de cliente. Output: [615251426, 653654874, 763654855, 863654874, 987654321]
[manuel SANCHEZ ORTIZ, manuel SANCHEZ ORTIZ, manuel SANCHEZ ORTIZ, manuel SANCHEZ ORTIZ, manuel SANCHEZ ORTIZ]

Comment: es raro.., su codigo se aparece correcto.. La posibilidad es algo cambia los valores de treemap en el medio del ejecucion, o probablemente hay errores temporal de factores externos (?) Prueba crear un nuevo file o restart la computadora

Answer (score 0):

El programa no funcionaba a causa de que los atributos nombre y apellidos, así como sus métodos GET estaban declarados como "static", cuando no deberían. Gracias igualmente por la ayuda.

```
package establecimiento;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

public class Cliente {

```
static String nombre,apellidos;
static Date FechaDeAlta = new Date(); 
static String telefono;
static String direccion;

static ArrayList<Pedido> historial= new ArrayList<Pedido>();

static boolean correcto=true;
static Pedido nuevoPedido;
static Cliente cliente;

public Cliente(String nombre,String apellidos,String f,String telefono,String direccion) {
    this.setNombre(nombre);
    this.setApellidos(apellidos);
    this.setFechaDeAlta(f);
    setTelefono(telefono);
    this.setDireccion(direccion);
}



// Sobrecarga de Cliente añadiendo el atributo historial
public Cliente(Cliente cli,ArrayList<Pedido> historial) {
    cliente=cli;
    setHistorial(nuevoPedido);
}

// Métodos GET SET
    
public void setNombre(String nom) {
    // Nos aseguramos que que el nombre sólo tenga letras
    boolean esLetra=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < nom.length(); i++) {
        if (!((nom.charAt(i)>='a' && nom.charAt(i)<='z') || (nom.charAt(i)>='A' && nom.charAt(i)<='Z'))) {
            System.out.println("Error, el nombre contiene un caracter que no es una letra");
            esLetra = false;
        }
    }
    if(esLetra==true) {
        nombre=nom.toLowerCase();
    }
}
public static String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setApellidos(String ape) {
    // Nos aseguramos que el apellido sólo tenga letras o espacio en blanco
    boolean esLetra=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length(); i++) {
        if (!((ape.charAt(i)>='a' && ape.charAt(i)<='z') || (ape.charAt(i)>='A' && ape.charAt(i)<='Z' || ape.charAt(i)==' '))) {
            System.out.println("Error, el apellido contiene un caracter que no es una letra o espacio");
            esLetra = false;
        }
    }
    if(esLetra==true) {
        apellidos=ape.toUpperCase();
    }
    
}
public static String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}


public void setFechaDeAlta(String f){
    
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        FechaDeAlta = sdf.parse(f);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static Date getFechaDeAlta() {
    return FechaDeAlta;
}

public static void setTelefono(String tel) {
    
    // Nos aseguramos que no hayan espacios en blanco
    tel.trim();
    tel.replace(" ","");
            
    // Comprobamos que los caracteres sean numéricos
    for(int i=0;i<tel.length();i++){
          if(tel.charAt(i)<48 || tel.charAt(i)>57) {
            System.out.println("Error, hay un valor no numérico en el teléfono");
                correcto=false;                                  
            }
    }
    // Comprobamos que el número de teléfono tenga 9 dígitos y que empiece por 6,7,8 o 9
    if(tel.length()!=9) {
        System.out.println("Error, el número de dígitos del teléfono es incorrecto");
        correcto=false;
    }
    if(tel.charAt(0)!='6' && tel.charAt(0)!='7' && tel.charAt(0)!='8' && tel.charAt(0)!='9') {
        System.out.println("Error,el número de teléfono no puede empezar con "+tel.charAt(0));
        correcto=false;
    }
    telefono=tel;
    
} 

public static String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setDireccion(String dir) {
    direccion=dir;
}
public static String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}


public static void setHistorial(Pedido p) {
    historial.add(p);
}
public static ArrayList<Pedido> getHistorial() {
    return historial;
}  



// Otros Métodos


public static void realizarPedido(Cliente p,Date f,ArrayList<Producto> pro,double impt,PasarelaDePago pa,String est) { 
    nuevoPedido = new Pedido(p,f,pro,impt,pa,est);
    agregarPedido(nuevoPedido);
}


public static void agregarPedido(Pedido nuevoPedido){
    
    if(Pedido.getEstado()=="PAGADO") {
        historial.add(nuevoPedido);
    }else {
        System.out.println("No se puede añadir el pedido, no está pagado");
    }
    //nuevoPedido=null;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    
    
    
        return getNombre()+" "+getApellidos();
    
}
```

}